# Reliable fast way from GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime() to local time

Tags: c++, winapi, time, timezone, localtime

WinAPI function `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()` writes the time to a `FILETIME` structure and that time is UTC. I would like to get the local time with microseconds and hundred-nanoseconds. I would like this algorithm to be first of all reliable, then fast.

The problem is that all WinAPI I've considered so far seems unreliable:

1. `FileTimeToLocalFileTime()` seems unreliable because [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724277(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> To account for daylight saving time when converting a file time to a
>   local time, use the following sequence of functions in place of using
>   FileTimeToLocalFileTime...

2. However, the suggested in the above sequence function `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` also seems unreliable because [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> The SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime function may calculate the local
>   time incorrectly under the following conditions:
>
> a) The time zone uses a
>   different UTC offset for the old and new years.
>
> b) The UTC time to be
>   converted and the calculated local time are in different years.

Case a) doesn't seem important, however, I would definitely like the algorithm to work correctly around New Year.

Finally, I've considered [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj206642(v=vs.85).aspx), however, it's not clear to me how it's different from `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` and its documentation doesn't seem trustworthy: it says that `lpTimeZoneInformation` parameter is optional, but it doesn't say how to specify the default value (is it `NULL`?) and how the function would behave in that default case (would it assume current timezone?).

The next part of the algorithm is to extract sub-millisecond values, as they are not provided by `SYSTEMTIME` structure. Can I just take `N%10000` where N is `uint64_t` value stored in `FILETIME` structure?

Comment: Precision and accuracy aren't the same thing, which you appear to believe. What do you need? Precision or accuracy?

Comment: Local time is meant for humans, convert to UTC as early as possible for input and as late as possible for output.  Basically string conversion, program logic should be strictly utc-based.  And no, the clock does not have infinite precision, nothing close to 100 nsec.  It gets updated by the clock interrupt handler, ticks 64 times per second by default.  That can be jacked up by timeBeginPeriod(), but you can't get close.  Such high precision is completely meaningless anyway, you can easily suffer a stall of hundreds of msec in userland.

Comment: I'm fine with the precision of `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()`. And even user stalls are not a problem because they don't happen frequently or systematically. What I'm not fine with is wrong hours and above (days, months, years) appearing due to WinAPI functions converting on the path from `FILETIME` to user-readable local time. And I couldn't find any such reliable path by reading MSDN.

Comment: It turns out that Raymond Chen [has a dedicated tag on his MSDN-hosted blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/time) collecting his posts on time, many of which deal with converting between system-provided time formats.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` and `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx` is that the latter uses a `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure, which properly reflects all of the year-over-year information from the Windows registry.

The `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure does *not* have any year-over-year changes to time zone information.  It only reflects the current active rule.  If you are working with arbitrary date-time values, you should avoid using this structure, as you have no guarantee that the current rule is the correct rule for the date-time you're working with.

However, if all you care about is the *current* time, then it is not necessary to concern yourself with year-over-year changes.  Even if you are getting the time near the beginning or end of the year, Windows will update the current time zone rule at the appropriate time.

Additionally, with both the `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` and `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx` functions, the time zone argument is optional.  Passing `NULL` will use the current local time zone.  This is documented on `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`:

> If `lpTimeZone` is `NULL`, the function uses the currently active time zone.

It's missing from the docs on `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx`, but has the same effect.

So, to get the current local time with all available precision the OS can supply, then:

1. `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`
2. `FileTimeToSystemTime`
3. `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`  (`Ex` not necessary here, and leave tz null)
4. `SystemTimeToFileTime`
5. Copy over sub-milliseconds from step 1 to the result of step 4.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need the dynamic structure when fetching the current time?  Isn't the "current active rule" exactly what you need?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the risk is that after `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()` the "active rule" may change before any further WinAPI call, e.g. `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()`. Even the year may change in between. And I wouldn't like the program to fail miserable on year change.

Comment: @Matt, but do I have to call `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation()`? Wouldn't it work if `NULL` is passed as the first argument of `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx()` -
 `lpTimeZoneInformation` ?

Comment: Yeah I think you might be right about that.  I need to test it out to be sure.  Anyway, at least you know the difference between dynamic and regular.  It matters much more when converting an arbitrary time than with the current time.

Comment: Updated to reflect this discussion.  The risk Serge mentioned would only matter if the year changed between steps 1 and 3 above.

Comment: I don't think SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() is not so much about length of program execution than converting dates where DST rules may have changed or are scheduled to change in the future. E.g. if you have a 10 years old file date,  and there were DST rules changes for that timezone, SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() will give you the correct  local date as it was 10 years ago. I think it will become very useful once DST is removed in Europe in the near future.

Comment: @Niki - Correct.  That's the point I was making about whether the use case is for the current time only, or if you are considered with year-over-year changes.  In the latter case, the "Ex" version is essential - otherwise you'd be applying the current rule to an old date.

Answer (score 1):

SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() is more reliable because retains the DST changes history for the timezone, where DST rules may have changed or are scheduled to change in the future.

E.g. if you have a 10 years old file date, and there were DST rules changes for that timezone, SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() will give you the correct local date as it was 10 years ago.

SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() will become very useful once DST is removed in Europe in the near future to have correct historical look on the local time.

E.g. Let say a JPEG file is saved to disk with proper Date Taken in EXIF stored as local date string. OS writes file date as UTC in the file system. When converting the UTC file date to local date for display, it must be exactly the same as the EXIF stored local date string. If there is DST mismatch, the dates won't be the same.

SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime() will work mostly, unless the DST rules have changed between NOW and the past when file was created, as in the case if the DST was removed. That's why SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx() must be used to get correct local date in DST historical perspective.

I don't know if there are downsides using SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx(), like performance.